# Context & Uri between classes set

Tags: java, android

I got a class, its need variable Context & Uri

How can I call this function from another class

I put MainActivity.this, uri

But there is still got a NULL String

Why the method "send" does not go though?

---

Main.class

```
 String predict = "Default";
 predict = VisionClient.send(MainActivity.this, uri);
 Log.e("try","predict =>>>>>>> " + predict); // predict got "Default"
```

---

VisionClient.class

```
public final static String send(Context context, Uri uriImage) throws Exception{

        InputStream credentialsStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.calories_4348f6cf420);
        GoogleCredential credential = null;

            credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialsStream, AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory()).createScoped(VisionScopes.all());

        Vision vision  = new Vision(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), credential);
        String path = ImagenMediaStoreUtils.getPath(context, uriImage);
        File wiki_path = new File(path);
        Image image = new Image().encodeContent(readFileToBytes(wiki_path));


        BatchAnnotateImagesRequest content = new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest();

        Feature textDetection = new Feature();
        textDetection.setType("TEXT_DETECTION");
        textDetection.setMaxResults(1);


        List<Feature> featureList = Lists.newArrayList();
        featureList.add(textDetection);


        List<AnnotateImageRequest> anImgReqList = Lists.newArrayList();

        AnnotateImageRequest annotatedImageReq = new AnnotateImageRequest();
        annotatedImageReq.setFeatures(featureList);
        annotatedImageReq.setImage(image);

        anImgReqList.add(annotatedImageReq);

        content.setRequests(anImgReqList);

        BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = vision.images().annotate(content).execute();

        if(response.getResponses() == null || response.getResponses().get(0) == null
                || response.getResponses().get(0).getTextAnnotations() == null
                || response.getResponses().get(0).getTextAnnotations().get(0) == null
                || response.getResponses().get(0).getTextAnnotations().get(0).getDescription() == null){
            throw new Exception("response null");
        }
        return response.getResponses().get(0).getTextAnnotations().get(0).getDescription();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you do two things:

1. Call the send method from within a thread, otherwise Android will
   throw an error, something like
2. context is a class variable within MainActivity, which you'll initialize in onCreate with

`context = this;`

and

```
try {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                String response = null;
                try {
                    response = VisionClient.send(context, photoFile, mCurrentPhotoPath);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                txtComputerVisionTextResult.setText(response);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "response = " + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
        );
        t1.start();
```